Can PlantUML generate nested/embedded block components and reference them via a dict "[]" or dot notation "."?
Given a diagram that looks like this following:

Where the components are defined in a nested manner, something like (ignore the actual semantics as I'm generalizing, though I'm welcome to full example):
component {
  name: A
  component {
    name: B
    ports {
      name: p1
    }
  }
...

Can you access nested components like any:
1)  A.B.p1 --> C.D.E.p4
2)  [A][B][p.1] --> [C][D][E][p.4]
3)  A["B"]["p.1"] --> C["D"]["E"]["p.4"]

I'm only generally seeing support for coding the connections like below. Even when components might be defined in a nested structure, the connection endpoints have to have a unique name:
1)  p.1 --> p.4
2)  A.B --> C.D.E (This fails, instead it creates NEW components "A.B"...)
3)  B[p.1] --> E[p.4] (Haven't ever seen this)

I have had success using component "E" as C.D.E {, but it's more of a hack in the naming of the components and not actually accessing via nesting:
@startuml
left to right direction

component "A" as A {
    component "B" as A.B {
        port "p.1" as A.B.p1
    }
}

component "C" as C {
    component "B" as C.B {
        component "D" as C.B.D {
            port "p.4" as C.B.D.p4
        }
    }
}

A.B.p1 --> C.B.D.p4
@enduml


